# ORDER BY items must appear... but I have no ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I am getting the well-documented error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Here's my SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO PropertyList
            (PropertyID, Initials)
SELECT DISTINCT P.PropertyID, "vSTEBCodes"
FROM Property AS P INNER JOIN ValiditySTEBCodes AS VC 
              ON P.ControlNumber=VC.ControlNumber
```

As you can see there is no ORDER BY statement in sight.  Presumably there is an implied ORDER BY in there somewhere, but I can't see it.

I am running this statement against linked tables in MS Access that are linked to a SQL Server 2008 back-end.  When I run it from a full version of Access 2002, it runs without issue.  If I try to run it from an Access 2000 runtime I receive the error shown.

I know that Access has a tendency to re-write queries in the background before forwarding them to ODBC sources (especially multi-record INSERTs and UPDATEs).  I'm thinking that may be the issue.

Comment: It is saying that "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified." You need to supply an ORDER BY clause in there.to make it work.

Comment: Maybe Access is adding an `ORDER BY` for you. What is `"vSTEBCodes"`? Is that supposed to be a string literal, a column name, something else? If it's supposed to be a string, try to use `'single quotes'`, and also try using `GROUP BY P.PropertyID` instead of `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @AwesomeProgrammer no, that's not what the error message is saying. While every statement *should* probably have an `ORDER BY` to be predictable and repeatable, there is no such requirement.

Comment: I agree with @AwesomeProgrammer that you need an `order by` to make Access happy.  If `vSTEBCodes` is a string literal, try `order by P.PropertyID, 'vSTEBCodes'`.  Otherwise, try `order by P.PropertyID, VC.vSTEBCodes`

Comment: @Andomar but the error message SQL Server is returning is because Access *added* an `ORDER BY` and obviously picked the wrong column. Are you saying it did so because there is no `ORDER BY` clause? How does it pick which column(s) to use? How do we know it won't still add an invalid `ORDER BY` column? Won't using `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT` solve the issue? Also the comment seems to imply that any old `ORDER BY` clause will do, and that is not the case.

Comment: "vSTEBCodes" is a string literal.

Comment: Also, I am having trouble re-producing the error.  The specific user who was having the issue is now gone for the day.  The fact it is not reproducible lends some weight to @Aaron's point that an ORDER BY should be included for repeatability.  Perhaps the problem is rooted in how Access is translating the DISTINCT clause.  In that case the better workaround might be to replace the DISTINCT clause with a functionally similar GROUP BY clause, as Aaron also suggested.

Comment: If it is a string literal then please stop enclosing it in double quotes, also provide it with an alias, e.g. `Initials = 'vSTEBCodes'`.

Comment: If the error comes up again, I will try replacing DISTINCT with GROUP BY.  If that fixes it, I will post the results as an answer and accept accordingly.  Thanks for everyone's help.  Sorry I can't provide a resolution today.

Comment: Check to see if the table you are inserting into has a trigger. Could be trigger code that is bad not Access code. Further use Profiler to see exactly what code Access is sending SQl server, that might help figure out the problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling from the comments, try:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.PropertyList(PropertyID, Initials)
  SELECT P.PropertyID, Initials = 'vSTEBCodes' -- alias and single quotes
  FROM dbo.Property AS P -- always use schema prefix
  INNER JOIN dbo.ValiditySTEBCodes AS VC 
  ON P.ControlNumber = VC.ControlNumber
  GROUP BY P.PropertyID  -- instead of DISTINCT
  ORDER BY P.PropertyID; -- maybe overrides Access stupidity
```